# What is optimal way to pipe one stream to two streams in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'm using a ReadableStream from request.js to pipe() a resource from http to a file system WritableStream.

How do I modify this to be able to process the content in memory? (for streamed parsing or whatever)

Ideally a full 'dupe' into two real streams and not just a callback 'tap' (but I'll take any advice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha, I had some lucky timing: the answer to my problem was announced today:

highlandjs, new stream util library by @caolan (the guy from `async`).

This is what I needed: http://highlandjs.org/#fork

It has the backpressure feature, lazy evaluation etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to firstly pipe the content from http.req into memory (Buffer) through a module named `memory-stream`. Then I create a readable from Buffer and pipe into file system. At the same time you can create multiple readable from this Buffer and pipe it to any writable.

In one of my projects I need to process thumbnail files in many sizes once I received an image uploaded from browser and I was using the approach above to implement, save the original image into Buffer and create readable steams for each size, pipe with `imagemagick` and then pipe file system writable stream to save in parallel.

Comment: I would prefer not to have whole file in memory but really stream it. But I can use `memorystream`, thx for the tip.

Comment: Yes I agree with you as if we put file into memory it might be very huge (in my case they are all images so should be a big problem). But when I pipe one readable to multiple writable I encountered a problem some of the writable did's receive any bits. I guessed this was because some writable consumed the stream very quick. I tried to pause the readable stream before piped and then resume but this caused more problem. So I have to use Buffer and it's very stable.

Comment: Found a solution, see the my answer.